# How do I open VMware Horizon View Client on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, vmware

So I downloaded VMware Horizon Client [here](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=CART16Q2_LIN64_410&productId=578&rPId=11464)

And I installed it using the command:

```
sudo sh VMware-Horizon-Client-3.5.0-2999900.x64.bundle
```

I followed the installer steps and my computer said it was successfully installed, but I do not see it where my applications would be. Did I do something wrong? How do I start it? Or where do I find the application?

Comment: Also, I have added Canonical Partners in the Other Software tab in Ubuntu Software and I can't find VMware when I do a search in Ubuntu Software.

Comment: It seems as though the 16.04 vmware-view-client source code hasn't been made available yet or packaged for xenial, If you've enabled the partner repo, search for vmware-manager or some of the other utilities that VMware provides and  you should see them.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got the old 3.5 version. I'm running 4.1, which is available from [the same URL](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=CART16Q2_LIN64_410&productId=578&rPId=11464) that you posted. Once installing, then it's available in the menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zach,

Open a terminal and type in:

```
vmware-view
```

This should open the VMware Horizon Client Gui where you can add your Server or Connections.

You will notice in the Unity Launcher an Icon for View, right click and select `Lock to Launcher`

[image: VMware Horizon Client Launcher Icon, Lock to Launcher]

Next time use the icon to launch it, hope this helps.

Comment: Wish I had more reputation so I could upvote your comment. :P

Comment: @ZachBryant, I think you do now! :)